# NpgsqlConnection hangs for hours on opening connection

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, amazon-redshift, npgsql

I was able to successfully connect using Npgsql nuget package, until one day the program started hanging for hours on executing conn.Open() without returning.
I can successfully connect with Aginity client with same parameters.
I tried **Firewall** On and Off.
I tried **Antivirus** On and Off.
I tried **Fiddler** On and Off.

Some things to Note:
I need to be on **VPN** to connect to that host. It just hangs for hours, when conn.Open() is executed. 
When I am not on VPN, it times out immediately.
We can't see actual incoming connections to the host, just queries. But the code doesn't get to the query part, it hangs on opening connection.

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();                                
                using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(command, conn))
                ...
```

Comment: This is likely to be some sort of network issue that's not really related to Npgsql... When your connection attempt is hanging, try to establish a connection to your database via other means (e.g. pgadmin, psql, telnet to port 5432). If those hang as well, this would confirm that the problem is unrelated to Npgsql.

Comment: Thanks. I can connect with Aginity client, while Npgsql is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that in Aginity client,  SSL Mode is set to **Require** and default value in Npgsql for SSL Mode is **Disable**, according to docs(https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html).
But when I am setting SSL Mode parameter of **Require** in connection string, I get the following exception:
Npgsql.PostgresException: 42704: unrecognized configuration parameter "ssl_renegotiation_limit"

While looking online for possible solution, I found this thread created by Npgsql nuget package owner. And from what it looks like, it may be an issue, that's in a feature request state:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229990