# Npgsql. unrecognized configuration parameter "ssl_renegotiation_limit"

Tags: c#, amazon-redshift, npgsql

Encountered this error, while trying to debug my other issue([NpgsqlConnection hangs for hours on opening connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218192/npgsqlconnection-hangs-for-hours-on-opening-connection)).

When I provide SSL Mode parameter of Require in connection string, I get the following exception: Npgsql.PostgresException: 42704: unrecognized configuration parameter "ssl_renegotiation_limit"

While looking online for possible solution, I found this thread created by Npgsql nuget package owner. And from what it looks like, it may be an issue, that's in a feature request state: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229990

Comment: postgres or redshift? please remove 1 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what's going on because you're not including any details on your PostreSQL version. However, All recent versions of PostgreSQL recognize (and ignore) `ssl_renegotiation_limit`. You're either using a very old version of PostgreSQL, or possibly Amazon Redshift, in which case you need to add `Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift` [as specified in the Npgsql docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/compatibility.html#amazon-redshift).